# trying to build a mySQL database from a JSON format, but can't figure out how

Tags: mysql, json, database-design

I currently have this JSON file which records a User's answers to given questions and does some calculations based on the answers. As I was working on Frontend, Using a json was more handy. The username and password system are without any security and were made just for the test. Now I'm trying to build a mySQL database with a more secure user account system but I can't seem to figure out a way of building tables that do the same thing as this file.

```
{ 
"username" : "a6",
"password" : "password", 
"joined" : 1621995190170,
"progress" : [
   { 
      "Question ID" : "00001", 
      "Question" : "-----",
      "SetAnswer" : "xxxxx", 
      "Recorded" : "yyyyy", 
      "Score" : 945, 
      "AttemptedAt" : 1611682870221, 
      "Factor" : 4,
      "AttemptAgain" : 1617014020591
   }, 
   { 
      "Question ID" : "00002", 
      "Question" : "-----",
      "SetAnswer" : "xxxxx", 
      "Recorded" : "yyyyy", 
      "Score" : 945, 
      "AttemptedAt" : 1611682870254, 
      "Factor" : 4,
      "AttemptAgain" : 1617014020564
   }, 
   { 
      "Question ID" : "00003", 
      "Question" : "-----",
      "SetAnswer" : "xxxxx", 
      "Recorded" : "yyyyy", 
      "Score" : 945, 
      "AttemptedAt" : 1611682870254, 
      "Factor" : 4,
      "AttemptAgain" : 1617014020564
   }...
(it goes on for 10,000+ entries)
```

The problem I got is there's a lot of things to record for each question from each user and making a table for each user will be a pretty bad idea. Any help with designing the SQL database would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating a table with columns "question id", "question", "setanswer", "recorded", "score", "attemptedat", "factor", "attemptagain"?

Comment: Agreed with mkrieger1. Create a "Users" table take the "id" of a user and link it to the questions tables and insert entries based on the information.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes I thought of it, but 12000 rows per user would make that table's row count go way too high right? I was always in an opinion that higher row count (in order of 100k or millions) would affect efficiency, is that not the case?

Comment: @Achs98: It depends on the number of users if you get 'a lot of' records, but you need a lot of user to go 'way too high'.   BTW how high is 'way too high'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [entity-relationship data design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).  You have three entities

- user
- question
- answer

Each entity gets its own table.

Your entities have these relationships.

- Each user can have zero or more answers.  So your answers table needs a `user_id` colum.
- Each question can also have zero or more answers.  So your  answers table needs a `question_id` column also.

From your Javascript object examples, I get these three table definitions.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE user (
  user_id         BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  hashed_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  joined          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE question (
  question_id     BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  question        VARCHAR(1000),
  set_answer      VARCHAR(1000),
  factor          FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.0,
  PRIMARY KEY (question_id)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE answer (
  answer_id       BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id         BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  question_id     BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  recorded_answer VARCHAR(1000),
  score           FLOAT,
  attempted       TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  attemted_again  TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (answer_id)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci';
```

Once these tables are populated you can get a resultset similar to your example with a query like this.

```sql
SELECT user.user_id, user.username, user.joined,
       question.question_id, question.question, 
       question.set_answer, question.factor,
       answer.recorded_answer, answer.score, 
       answer.attempted, answer.attempted_again
  FROM user
  LEFT JOIN answer   ON user.user_id = answer.user_id
  JOIN question ON answer.question_id = question.question_id
```

Here's what is going on.

- The `user_id`, `question_id`, and `answer_id` numbers uniquely identify each user, question, and answer.
- The SELECT clause enumerates the data you want.
- The FROM clause indicates that you want results user-by-user.
- The LEFT JOIN clause implements the relationship that a user can have zero or more answers. You can think of `answer.user_id` as pointing back to the user.
- The JOIN clause implements the relationship stating each anser must have one question. `question_id` points back to the question.

And, by the way, SQL database systems including MySQL can handle millions of rows in various tables without breaking a sweat, so don't worry about that. (You may need to add indexes when the tables get that big, but that comes after you make your app work correctly.)

Comment: wow thanks a lot man, really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. Pay it forward!